# Updating Chart.js labels with Alpine.js and Livewire breaks chart

Tags: chart.js, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am using Alpine.js with Livewire to update a Chart.js chart dynamically.

I am updating the chart every 30 seconds via entangling with Alpine and Livewire. The updates work perfectly fine forever when I only update the values. But if I try to update the labels as well it works 2 times then breaks (screenshot below, that straight diagonal line is not supposed to be there). I have tried removing the values before resetting them but that does not make any difference.

```
<div wire:ignore x-data="{
fillColor: @entangle('fillColor').live,
lineColor: @entangle('lineColor').live,
chartData: @entangle('chartData').live,
timeframe: @entangle('timeframe').live,
init() {
    const Labels = this.chartData.map(item => item.time);
    const Values = this.chartData.map(item => item.close);

//MORE STYLING and SETTINGS for Chart.JS

Livewire.on('updateChart', () => {
        {{-- chart.data.datasets[0].data.pop(); --}}
        chart.data.labels = this.chartData.map(item => item.time);
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.chartData.map(item => item.close);
        chart.update();
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY! I figured it out. I was not clearing the array in the livewire controller before sending the data back to Alpine.js....